# 'https:///%3Cdatabricks-instance%3E/api/2.0/clusters/get': No host supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, databricks

I am trying to create groups in databricks notebook using python 3.0.
I am trying to call API using python command.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer PID-DataBricks-Token',
}

params = (
    ('cluster_id', '1204-115751-tear912/'),
)
response = requests.get('https:///%3Cdatabricks-instance%3E/api/2.0/clusters/get', headers=headers, params=params)
print(response.status_code)
```

but I get this error:

> 'https:///%3Cdatabricks-instance%3E/api/2.0/clusters/get': No host supplied

Comment: Remove the %3C-

Comment: `%3Cdatabricks-instance%3E` - should be replaced with the actual host name

Comment: if you're trying to create groups, then you're using wrong API